# Elasticsearch custom stemming algorithm

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, stemming

I am in the process of moving an application from dtSearch to elasticsearch, and wanted to keep the same features without changing the end user's process. The main one I'm having trouble with is stemming. We allow the user to specify their own stemming rules in the dtSearch format:

```
3+ies  -> y
3+ing  ->
```

Where the `3` is the number of preceding characters, the `ies` is the suffix and the `y` is what to replace it with. Is it possible to specify a custom algorithm to elasticsearch (well... the lucene engine) so that the user wont have to update their stemming rules to conform to a new search service? Or are the two methods mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

For a painful, extremely dirty solution, you can use regular expressions.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html

---

Otherwise, you'll have to create your own Elasticsearch analysis plugin (with a token-filter implementation that does what you want, in java).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugin-authors.html

It'll perform best if you can express your stemming rules as a DFA in memory.  There are several java Automata libraries out there you can use.  (e.g. http://www.brics.dk/automaton/faq.html)